# How to output scikit learn classification report in percent?

Tags: python, python-2.7, numpy, scikit-learn

Is it possible to output with scikit-learn classification report in percent?. Let's assume I print the classification report like this:

```
from sklearn.metrics import classification_report
y_true = [0, 1, 2, 2, 0]
y_pred = [0, 0, 2, 1, 0]
target_names = ['class 0', 'class 1', 'class 2']
print(classification_report(y_true, y_pred, target_names=target_names))
```

and I want get output in percent(*100):

```
 precision    recall  f1-score   support

class 0       67      100      80         2
class 1       0       0        0          1
class 2       100     50       67         2
```

`avg / total   67      60       59         5`

Comment: I don't think this is easily possible without hacking the classification_report source code

Answer (score -1):

[The only option in the current version (0.18.1)](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.metrics.classification_report.html) is to change the print precision using the `digits` parameter, but it will always be a ratio.

You could write a function that parses the output string and converts the ratio into percent.